# LIKE to select the independent existence of the word whereever in the text

Tags: sql-server-2008, query, pattern-matching

[image]

I have a table with the following texts and the key word i am searching for is 'Search'.So i have written a query

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[TextValue]
FROM
   [dbo].[SearchLike]
WHERE
   [TextValue] LIKE '%Search%'
```

**Q.1** How can i modify the query so that only the records having 'Search' in the text is returned and it shouldn't be taking 'LSearch'. i.e as per the image first three records only to be returned.?

Comment: because of Search and LSearch is some replacement parameter (I think), use: s.z NOT LIKE '%LSearch%' AND s.z LIKE '%Search%'

Comment: good question, since many of us not aware of available wildcard characters that can be used with LIKE. I'm adding this [link/reference](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-asarc/srg1100e/sqlref/@Generic__BookTextView/73386;pt=73946), which may help anyone who wants to know more about it.

Comment: and one from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Using LIKE

- Single line like search:

  ```
  WHERE
   ' ' + [TextValue] + ' ' LIKE '%[.,;:() ]Search[.,;:() ]%'

  /* [] contains list of allowable characters, adding spaces around 
     [TextValue] removes need to have multiple OR [TextValue] LIKE */
  ```
- Without padding you will need to specifically handle string appearing at start/end of string:

  ```
  WHERE
      [TextValue] LIKE '%Search%' --middle
      OR
      [TextValue] LIKE 'Search%'   --start
      OR
      [TextValue] LIKE '%Search'   --end
  ```

### Using FULLTEXT INDEX

Edit2, for the full text purists

[`CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx) on MSDN states for the AUTO option (the default)

> Although changes are propagated automatically, these changes might not be reflected immediately in the full-text index.

So, it may not give correct results. But then a few seconds later it will.

Also, for upto a few 10k rows it will perform adequately: it scales O(n). I use the LIKE on a table with around 25k rows but users know it will perform badly if they search this way (it's on an "advanced" page). I gain in the trade off by managing a full text index

Full text search isn't *the* correct solution, it's *one* option

**Note:** Experience has shown me that FullText indexing in SQL Server has severe performance implications, ie: Only implement if you really need to and you know what you're doing! (@Andrew Bickerton)

Comment: It looks fine.But is there any other way i could bring it through any wild card expressions?.Actually i am implementing it in a search query.And am trying to reduce the line of code.

Comment: I tried by adding spaces but it is not returning the first record i.e the key word at the beginning of the text.

Comment: @balu: Are you running this *exact* code after my edit?

Comment: I don't like downvoters. Don't worry. If my quick answer was incorrect, I thank you for cold water. I had not time to quick response(edit) my answer.

Comment: This isn't a scalable solution.  In will use an index scan or table scan.  As the table grows the amount of time searching the table will grow dramatically.  The full text option shown is the one which should be used.

Comment: @mrdenny: upto a few 10k rows it won't matter. It scales O(n). Also, from CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX  with the AUTO option, "Although changes are propagated automatically, these changes might not be reflected immediately in the full-text index."

Comment: @gbn I missed the space so it didn't worked.Now i just copied your exact code and it is working.However you can observe the third record having 'Search.' is missing in such cases.Is there any chance were i could allow special characters at the end (.,;:) while using % Search % ?

Comment: Correct full text index population isn't synchronous like a normal index.  Typically searches of large text data it is acceptable to have a short period when new or changed rows aren't returned by the index.  I would assume that this table will eventually scale beyond a few thousand records.  If a developer at my shop presented this query to me, it would never see the light of production.

Comment: @gbn how the multiple OR is done with adding spaces between [textvalue]?Can you give a brief comment on it.

Answer (score 6):

If your table will have a non-trivial amount of rows, you might want to try a FULLTEXT index instead. It will be much faster and will match just on the exact word.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG <catalog_name> AS DEFAULT;

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[SearchLike](TextValue)
    KEY INDEX pk_id; --requires the existing of a PK or UQ index with this name on this table
```

Now search for your text:

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[TextValue]
FROM
   [dbo].[SearchLike]
WHERE
   CONTAINS([TextValue], 'Search')
```

More on:

- [CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189520.aspx)
- [CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx)
- [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)
- [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Comment: Full text search within SQL Server will be the only efficient way to search the data.  Any other way that I can think of would require an index or table scan.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if SQL server supports `\b` in regexes (match on word boundry).  And you'll have to [create a user defined function to allow regex matching in the first place](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx), but if it does, you could match on:

```
\bSearch\b
```

If it doesn't, you should still be able to match on:

```
(^| )Search( |$)
```

Comment: At this time, SQL Server does not support native regex searches using LIKE. CLR is an option, but a slow one.